# How to calculate the roots of Quadratic Equation in MIPS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm really stucked with the idea of this question, has anyone experiences something similar before to provide me the solution ?

Write a MIPS assembly language program to solve a quadratic equation: a(x^2)+b(x)+c= 0.

Ask the user to enter the coefficients a, b, and c, which should be double-precision floating-point numbers. Calculate and display the roots of the quadratic equation, which should also be double-precision numbers. Handle all cases, including the case of complex roots.

really thankful for your help.

Comment: this is not how it works. please post the code you have so far and the specific problem you're encountering. not even trying to rephrase your assignment is not good style, you're not demonstrating any effort you might have made so far.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking up some algorithms for solving quadratic equations (in any computer language), and then once you have a good algorithm in your head, program it in assembly.

Work on one small piece of the program at a time. For example, get the user input working first. Then work on the general algorithm. Then work on corner cases. Etc. Remember, if things get too complex, maybe you need to add another layer of abstraction (if that's possible in assembly...).

I'm intentionally not getting specific because I don't want to do your homework for you. :)